# Options for pure-number module namespace?

Tags: haskell

It seems a pure-number module namespace like

```
module 2010.Foo where
```

is not allowed.

One not so pretty option would be

```
module V2010.Foo where
```

Can you suggest other options?

Comment: `module TwoThousandTen.Foo where` :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Module names must start with a capital letter. The module name must also be the same as the file name, so as far as module naming goes you really only have one option: start the name with a capital letter.

Answer (score 0):

Is `V2010` meant to represent a version number?

If so, you should probably handle versioning through [Cabal](http://www.haskell.org/cabal/) and not in the module namespace directly.

Comment: I want to track forms, which change every year. The plan is to keep them in the same repository in different directories so that the newer ones can refer to the older ones.